# Constuct a dynamic link in an email where landing form is determined by a link in the list item field

Tags: email, hyperlink, links-list

I have a travel request application working well in sharepoint.  My workflow determines which form is opened based on an item link in a sharepoint list.  The address of the link is reset for different stages of completion. (i.e. the link initially points to an edit form but once the travel request is submitted my workflow readdresses the link to point to a display form for the same item.)

My question is, Can I construct an email link that will send the user to the current address of the link in the list.  I am trying to use this method to prevent the initial email from being opened again at a later time and opening the edit form when is should render the display form.

Comment: Do you want the url of display form of current item or what?